# Hide a div with angular if the input field is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

At the moment my code works if the view loads and there is no focus in the input field. The div is hidden with this code:

```
<i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Solothurn durchsuchen..." name="text" ng-model="searchBox.storeName">
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card has-header" ng-show="searchBox">
      <div class="w shop">{{item.storeName}}</div>
      <p class="w">
```

But my goal is, that when the user deletes the text in the input field the divs are again hidden. How can I do this? 
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `ng-show="searchBox.storeName"`

Comment: `ng-show` directive using `searchBox.storeName.length` ?

Comment: @olivier, Tushar is more accurate :)

Comment: @olivier And Rayon is more readable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use 
`ng-show="searchBox.storeName.length > 0"` and that'll server your purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card has-header" ng-if="searchBox.storeName != null">
```

**OR**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card has-header" ng-if="searchBox.storeName">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Solothurn durchsuchen..." name="text" ng-model="searchBox.storeName">
        </label>
        <br><br>
        <div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card has-header" ng-show="searchBox.storeName">
          <div class="w shop">{{item.storeName}}</div>
          <p class="w">
```